# Grey-out effect in UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` containing a container view, and that container is linked(embedded linked) to a `UITableViewController`. inside this `UITableViewController` I have two `UITableViewCells` added. When you click the **cell** and not the `UIObjects` inside the cell, the cell changes to a grey color, the gray highlight only disappears when you select the other `UITableViewCell`. I have tried using this to solve my problem, but it deactivates the `UIObjects` inside the cells, even when you use this code to reactivate the **.userEnteractionEnabled**

```
//Stop the UITableViewCell's from greying out
gcImageNameCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
gcBioCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

//But.. turn back on EVERYTHING ELSE
gcImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
gcGroupNameTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
gcGroupAcronymTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
gcTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

How do i get around this?

Comment: wow guys I apologize for the duplicate, I must have been searching all the wrong things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to prevent the cell from showing selection, you can do

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

Otherwise, please clarify your question.